# Can't see drop down list in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a very simple drop down list in excel.  It holds a sequence of integers loaded from a cell range (years).  I need to read the selected value in vba.  However I can't even seem to find the control!

I've tried

```
CboYear
Sheet2.CboYear
Worksheets("SheetName").CboYear
```

etc. etc.

From everywhere in VBA this control just doesn't exist.  All the tutorials I find seem to assume that using just the control name will work.

I've tried the code in the sheet itself, the workbook, and a module, no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got the drop down from the Forms toolbar, use

```
Sheet2.DropDowns("CboYear")
```

The DropDowns property is unsupported/deprecated so you won't get intellisense, but it still works.

If you got the drop down from the Control Toolbox, then

```
Sheet2.CboYear
```

should work

Comment: Unsupported/deprecated or just hidden?

Comment: You can get the Hidden classes to show in IntelliSense by changing the "Show Hidden Members" property within the "Object Browser". Right-click anywhere within the "Object Browser" and check "Show Hidden Members"

Comment: Maybe 'hidden' is the proper term.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of control sets used by *Excel*. The built-in controls and *Microsoft Forms 2.0* controls. The built-in controls available through the **Forms** toolbar are controls specifically designed to work within *Excel* and use ranges. The other controls are the *Microsoft Forms 2.0* controls. These are ActiveX controls that are used by *Office VBA*. The are designed to work within *Office* and are more similiar to the controls used by *Windows*.

Comment: When I run MsgBox Worksheets("SheetName").Shapes("CboYear") I get "Object does not support property or method"